# ElasticSearch - match_phrase_prefix query with synonyms

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

Is it possible to use match_phrase_prefix on the field which is using synonyms?

Details of this issue can be found here : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-search-issues-synonyms-issue/276750

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use it with synonyms when you are using search time synonyms, but if change your synonyms filter to be used during index time as the synonyms will be indexed you can use match_phrase_prefix and it will return results.
For more inforamtion about search time and index time synonyms check [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/boosting-the-power-of-elasticsearch-with-synonyms).

Comment: Thanks for your response on this. I will check on the link you provided.